# Equation or proper indexing in Microsoft Visio 2013

Tags: text-formatting, microsoft-visio-2013, equations

I am using Visio 2013 and I am trying to properly add an index to a variable c' (label of a square element) so that it is below the '. This is possible in Word 2013 using an equation, however I cannot copy and paste the equation to Visio (it's invisible there). If I just subscript the index, it is behind the ', not below:

[image]

I tried adding equations as and object in Visio using Microsoft Eqution-Editor 3.0, but it doesn't work with that either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: no proper way to do this I guess?

Answer (score 0):

I do t with an odd trick, copy the equation into paint and from paint copy it into visio as a picture object. However, you can write an equation as an object in visio but for me it is a time consuming task

Comment: Given that the OP pasted an image into the question, above, it's safe to assume that he knows how to copy and paste images.  If you know how to get the visual effect that the OP wants *in Visio* in a way that's native to Visio and editable in Visio, your answer would be immensely more useful and valuable if you presented that information.